# Is every ordinary coloured transparent paper an optical filter?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Can any red coloured transparent paper be used as an optical filter that only allows red colours through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For incoherent light, yes, though you would do well to measure the transmission spectrum to protect yourself from nasty surprises.

For a laser, you probably need professional filters with optics-quality surface roughness.

Answer (score 1):

Usually ordinary red transparent lets a broad range of wavelengths pass. So if your not to critical the answer is yes. If you need a narrow bandwidth you would do well to search for professional filters.